# How to retain a list/set of keys and remove other?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to merge 2 maps. Map1 and Map2. I also need to make sure that from Map2 only specific keys (stored in a predefined set) are added to the resultant map.

To merge maps I tried following and it works but not sure how to fit in my second requirement into this:

```
let mergedMap:Map<string, number> = new Map([...Array.from(map1.entries()), ...Array.from(map2.entries())]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right path, all you need to do is to filter out the 2nd map with whatever keys you might define:

```
const predefinedKeys = [ 'foo', 'bar' ];

const mergedMap: Map<string, number> = new Map([
  ...Array.from(map1.entries()),
  ...Array.from(map2.entries().filter(([ key ]) => predefinedKeys.includes(key)))
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map1 = new Map<string, number>();
map2 = new Map<string, number>();
mergedMap= new Map<string, number>();
predefinedKeys = [ 'AA', 'BB' ];

// merge map and filter
mergedMap = new Map([...Array.from(map1.entries()), 
   ...Array.from(map2.entries()).filter(([key]) => {
   return predefinedKeys.indexOf(key.toString()) > -1;
  })
]);

// print here
mergedMap.forEach((value: string, key: string) => {
  console.log(key, value);
 });
```